# Why does browser upload to S3 bucket return 403 forbidden?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, browser, amazon-s3

I've read dozens of proposed answers to this question online over the past few days, so I'm guessing the answer is pretty case-specific. I have a bucket for uploads from a Rails development app and have cors set up like this (for use with localhost):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
      <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
      <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
      <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
      <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
      <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
  </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

and I have a bucket policy set up like this:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": ID,
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": SID,
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm using dropzone with the s3_direct_upload gem, and that all seems to be working fine. I've double-checked key, secret, bucket name, and region. Do I also need an IAM policy in addition to the bucket policy?

Comment: What happens if you specify AllowedOrigin to localhost:<port>

Comment: The CORS configuration almost certainly has nothing to do with this error.  Can you capture the headers from the request and response, and the response body?

Comment: Specifying localhost doesn't change anything. 

I did find more from the response body: `Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["starts-with", "$content-type", ""]` so I tried adding `"Condition": ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""]` to the bucket policy, but the policy won't save with an `Invalid bucket policy syntax. - undefined` error.

Comment: Request `Accept:application/json
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:52262051
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarykqTgliRVKz5XVgVC
Host:s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/users/2
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: Response `Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:close
Content-Type:application/xml
Date:Sun, 12 Feb 2017 06:18:38 GMT
Server:AmazonS3
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
x-amz-id-2:aYqR8DbkeIHh1Tf+pZwh5x4o1qm/sgaXvbq7ex2ZyykpCJBzX7jrUXr9j0ui++l+rq0S3q2wEg4=
x-amz-request-id:577C3C4379DAEE89`